# Handling both static and non static functions in c++

Tags: c++

I have a c++ class, part of its defintion is:

```
template <class InputClass>
class MyClass
```

And `InputClass` is defined as a child class of MyClass:

`class InputClass: public MyClass<InputClass>`

there are many places in MyClass that has this call:

```
InputClass::AttributeName()
```

Where `AttributeName()` is defined on different child classes of InputClass as:

`static std::string AttributeName`

However, recently, there's specific child class of InputClass in which we have to define attributeName as non static, because we want different instances of this new child class to NOT share `AttributeName`):

`std::string AttributeName`

What modifications can I make such that I can still `AttributeName()` either as a static or non-static variable from inside `MyClass` ?

Comment: Is constructing `MyClass` with a reference to an instance of `InputClass` on the table?

Comment: @AndyG I edited the original question to add the fact that InputClass is is child class of MyClass already

Comment: In order to be able to call a non-static member function, you MUST have a pointer or reference to an object of type `InputClass`. It's hard to suggest how you get that without additional context.

Comment: @RSahu I modified the original question to add the fact that InputClass is already inheriting from MyClass

Comment: @user1008636, that's not sufficient.

Comment: "Where AttributeName() is defined on different child classes of InputClass?" Did you mean "different parent class"?

Comment: Can you give a short example of the code in MyClass, which wants to access the different AttributeNames? Does a function in MyClass get the specific instance of the InputClass as function parameter or do you want a list of all AttributeNames of all existing instances?

Comment: Why is the base class dependent on calling a member function of the derived class?  (Yes, it's a template argument, but that is effectively what you've set up).  That strikes me as a flawed design to start with.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I can't see how to make a static and a non-static member functions with the same name in derived classes and differentiate between them in the base class. Also, I don't know if there is a way to call a non-static member function which is declared in the derived class and is not declared in the base class.

If we omit those two requirements, then you could check whether the static function exists and call it, or fallback to a non-static (virtual) function otherwise (in my example I replaced your `AttributeName` function with `static_name` and `name` for static and non-static functions correspondingly):

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <experimental/type_traits>

template<class InputClass>
class Item {

    virtual std::string name() {
        return "none";
    };
    ...
public:
    virtual ~Item() = default;
    
    ...   
};

class DerivedNonStatic: public Item<DerivedNonStatic> {
    std::string name() final {
        return "non-static item";
    }
};

class DerivedStatic: public Item<DerivedStatic> {
public:
    static std::string static_name() {
        return "static item";
    }
};
```

Now, in the base `Item` class you can decide on which function to use like this:

```
class Item {
    
    template<typename T>
    using static_name_t = decltype(T::static_name); // static member function type
    static constexpr bool has_static_name = std::experimental::is_detected_v<static_name_t, InputClass>;

    void printName() {
        if constexpr(has_static_name) {
            std::cout << InputClass::static_name() << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << this->name() << std::endl;
        }
    };
    ...
}
```

And how it can be used in the client code:

```
int main() {
    DerivedNonStatic dns;
    dns.printName(); // prints "non-static item"

    DerivedStatic ds;
    ds.printName(); // prints "static item"
}
```